# Random sampling from two arrays without replacement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm writing a simple program in which I need to randomly sample all words from two lists, without repeating any words. This is in the broader context of an experiment with two conditions. The list I should draw from on each trial (frame) depends on which condition that trial is in. Here's what I have in mind:

```
condition = ["A", "B"]

listA = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
listB = ["desk", "chair", "lamp"]

if (condition == "A") {
    myWord = [word drawn from listA]
} else if (condition == "B") {
    myWord = [word drawn from listB]
}
```

In the example above, there would be 6 trials, 3 per condition, without any words being repeated. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `const lists = {A: listA, B: listB}; lists[condition];`

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me what this line does, and if/how it would fit into the if-then statement?

Comment: Creates a lookup map called `lists` that has your two lists. `lists[condition]` fetches either `listA` or `listB` based on the value of `condition`. It *replaces* the `if` statement, as there is no need for branching logic any more. You then fetch a random word from the list in a way that you prefer. `myWord = getSomeRandomWord(lists[condition])`

Comment: Got it working, thanks so much! For the benefit of others...older versions of javascript don't support `const` or `let`. If this is the case, replace both with `var` and it should work (at least it did for me with ECMA-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @VLAZ for providing this solution in the comments.

Simply replace the `if` statement with the following:

```
const lists = {A: listA, B: listB}; lists[condition];
```

Additional note: older versions of javascript don't support `const`. I found that using the following also works

```
var lists = {A: listA, B: listB}; lists[condition];
```